# Add through field of user to serializer

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm having the following models

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
  display_name = models.Charfield()

class Team(models.Model):
  display_name = models.Charfield()
  users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='TeamUser')

class TeamUser(models.Model):
  team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  role = models.IntegerField(_('role'), choices=[(g.id, g.name) for g in TeamRoles.all()], default=0)
  color = models.CharField(_('color'), max_length=10)
  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('team_id', 'user_id',)
```

I want to add role and color to Serializers (using request.user)
How can I make TeamSerializer for that?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to add something new to the incoming HTTP request you are getting. you need to inject it on the request. example.

```
self.request.GET.set('color', 'green') // this is in case of HTTP/GET
self.request.POST.set('color', 'green') // this is in case of HTTP/POST
```